# Control enable/disable state of link on web page using ajax external API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I think what I want is quite simple but I am not sure where to start. I want something like this on my web page:

[image]

And when the user clicks Yes or no, a background (AJAX) call goes out to URL that looks like this:

```
http://yesnoservice.com/helpful?value=yes+url="mywebpage.com/myurl/1"
```

Also: when the user clicks on the link, the text changes a little to not allow them to vote again so it might say. "Thank you for helping us improve our site."

I am using Bootstrap and JQuery. I was trying to experiment with JS Fiddle but really I am not sure how to put this together.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and it will be much faster to help you! If you haven't tried, take a look at $.post in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have not tried anything yet because I am stuck figuring out up from down. I have the web site working, I built the micro service that will handle the api call, and now I've come down to the html/js/jquery twiddling which I understand conceptually but not at the nuts and bolts level. I will look at $.post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your element in the page looks something like this:

```
<div id="helpful">
    Was this answer helpful?
    <a id="yes-link" ... >yes / <a id="no-link" ...>no
</div>
```

You need to bind a click event handler to these two elements. For one of the two, the code would look like this:

```
$("#yes-link").click(function () {
    // Do ajax call
    $.get("http://yesnoservice.com/helpful", {value: "yes", url:"mywebpage.com/myurl/1"}).done(function(data) {...});
    // Substitute content
    $("#helpful").html("Thank you for your response!");
});
```

This requires jQuery. If you're not familiar with it, I recommend reading the docs, they are quite easy to understand. Relevant pages for `$.get` and `.html`:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Thanks! That was just the bit of bootstrapping idea I needed!